# How to explain the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table called Employee, and it has a column named Courses. This column has four records which are 'English','Math','Music','Project'. So, I want to combine those rows into one and separate them by comma, so I search online to find solution and I found this one:

```
Declare @Name Varchar(100) = '';
Select  @Name = @Name + ',' + Course
From    Employee;
```

Although, it has correct outputs, but I still cannot get it and wondering how the results come out. To be specific, why @Name  = @Name +  can combine the rows together? Can anyone explain this to me a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

variable @name start empty string, it is important because if not initialized it would be NULL, and NULL plus something is NULL.

```
Declare @Name Varchar(100) = '';
```

then you assign at this variable its current value and add a comma and the course. This happens for each row

```
Select  @Name = @Name + ',' + Course From    Employee;
```

You could also specify an order and the generated string will match it.

For removing initial comma you can use

```
select Stuff(@name, 1, 1, '')
```

It means from character 1, replace 1 character with empty char

Answer (score 0):

The SQL engine has a built-in loop running behind the scenes when you select from Employee table.  The loop runs on each row and adds to itself.

This is a simplified answer, but hope it helps!

Comment: so, may I understand in this way, that every time you select from records from a column, the record is fetched one at a time, like a loop.

Comment: Conceptually, yeah pretty much.

The type of "loop" depends on a few things like if the table has an index or not, and you can see these types loops (e.g. Hash Lookup, Seek) in the query planner.  But conceptually, yes it's looping through the table.

Answer (score 0):

In short, This code is used to create a comma separated list from a table. Simply appending comma at the start of every row from `name` column. Though you're still having a comma at the start of the string, you can use `SUBSTRING` function to remove it.

Example based on `AdventureWorks2014` Database.

```
Declare @Name Varchar(100) = ''; Select  @Name = @Name + ',' + Name From    
Production.Product;

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name,2,LEN(@Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

This query means:

```
Select  @Name = @Name + ',' + Course
```

`Concatenation` of all `Course` field value with comma.

The variable `@name = @name` is your `holder` every time the query fetch the `course value` until its done.